# cannot open shared object file: Permission denied

Tags: redis, travis-ci, redisearch

I am successfully building the `redisearch.so` module on travis-ci.

After the module is built, I instruct the Redis to load it like this

```
redis-cli MODULE LOAD $TRAVIS_BUILD_DIR/rs/build/redisearch.so
```

which gives me the following error

```
5439:M 17 Nov 2020 09:12:55.341 # Module /home/travis/build/***/rs/build/redisearch.so failed to load: /home/travis/build/***/rs/build/redisearch.so: cannot open shared object file: Permission denied
```

this is what `ls -la /home/travis/build/***/rs/build/redisearch.so` gives me

```
-rwxrwxr-x 1 travis travis 2711408 Nov 17 09:12 /home/travis/build/***/rs/build/redisearch.so
```

**The question is: how do I fix this `permission denied` error?**

**PS**:

I have already tried to `chmod` and `chown` the `/home/travis/build/***/rs/build/redisearch.so` but with no luck.

Comment: Although it's not mentioned in [docs](https://redis.io/commands/module-load), I would try to escape the `*` characters by piping the command through `sed 's/*/\\*/g'`

Comment: Was selinux in my case. unconfined / user_home.

Answer (score -1):

Just move redisearch.so file into folder /etc/redis/

Comment: Note: answers that are very brief and/or are questions back to the poster should probably be comments. You only need 50 rep points to comment under a question - could you move this there?